# Problem with relative path in QTP AOM

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a QTP test that will be launched from a vbs script. The folder structure is like this:

```
-Root
   -QTP
     -scripts
        -script1
        -script2
   -Resources
      -scripts
```

inside Root\Resources\scripts I have the vbs that will launch QTP, and the following line:

```
qtApp.Open  "..\..\QTP\scripts\script1", True
```

However, when I try to run the vbs I get the Cannot open test error.

Is something I'm missing or doing wrong there?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think it supports relative paths

Comment: Yeah, we end up passing the root path as a parameter to the script and concatenating with our "relative" path. Thanks anyway!